# c++11 use chrono as syntactic sugar

Tags: c++, c++11

I use function from external library with interface like this:`void f(int timeout);`.
Where `timeout` is in milliseconds. To make my code more readable, I want to use `chrono` in such form:

```
f(std::chrono::milliseconds(10).count());
```

1. is it possible that `std::chrono::milliseconds(10).count() != 10` ?
2. is any "underwater rocks" that prevent modern compilers (clang, gcc, VC++) to convert  `f(std::chrono::milliseconds(10).count())` to `f(10)`?

Comment: Getting the count of a duration by itself makes no sense, it only makes sense when you compare it to another duration.

Comment: You should also consider using `operator""ms`. Instead of writing `std::chrono::milliseconds(10)` just write `10ms`.

Comment: semantic sugar lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. is it possible that `std::chrono::milliseconds(10).count() != 10` ?

No. The [`duration` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) you're using does:

> 3) Constructs a duration with `r` ticks.

and [`count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) simply:

> Returns the number of ticks for this duration.

---

> 2. is any "underwater rocks" that prevent modern compilers (clang, gcc, VC++) to convert `f(std::chrono::milliseconds(10).count())` to `f(10)`?

Nope. The `duration` constructor is `constexpr`, as is the `count()` member function you're using - that should be a very simple optimization for a compiler to make.

---

> To make my code more readable [...]

Personally, I find that questionable. If `f()` itself *took* a `duration`, then `f(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))` in of itself is certainly better than just `f(10)`, with the added benefit that whatever duration you pass in will work correctly. But if it's just taking an `int`, you're just giving yourself the illusion of security with just lots more typing. So I'm not sure it's any better, personally.

Comment: So you think, that when you see `f(10);` in code, and you need open documentation to find out in which units `f` accept timeout, is better then `f(std::chrono::milliseconds(10).count())` which document itself?

Comment: @user1244932 And if `f` takes a timeout in seconds? Either way, it's not any more self-documenting then `f(10); // milliseconds` or the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. But beware that the result is not milliseconds, but ticks. So `std::chrono::seconds(10).count()` is also 10. So you might want to do an assignment to a `std::chrono::milliseconds` variable first.
2. No, because the method is a `constexpr`. So any good compiler should respect that.